# How to make a query for mongodb using spring to return objects ordered alphabetically'

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have and class cleed `UserModel` with the `name` atribute. And i am trying make a method that return the hole users order alphabetically. My method:

```
@Query("{ 'name' : { $exists: true }}")
Page<UserModel> findAllByNameOrderByNomeAsc(Pageable pageable);
```

But this does not work. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your methods name findAllByNameOrderBy**Nome**Asc(Pageable pageable);

It should be findAllByNameOrderBy**Name**Asc(Pageable pageable);